# Mockito - matcher based on a specific property

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have a operationService class with executeOperation method which accept a databaserequest object .This databaserequest object has 4 properties , one of them is operation . I want to return different responses while calling operationService.executeOperation based on the databaserequest.operation field . Please help me on this .
This is what iam trying to achieve

```
 when(operationService.executeOperation(anyDatabaserequest object with operation as 'DEMO')).thenReturn('DEMO_RESPONSE');
 when(operationService.executeOperation(anyDatabaserequest object with operation as 'PILOT')).thenReturn('PILOT_RESPONSE');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mockito.argThat for this:

```
Mockito.when(obj.testMethod(Mockito.argThat(x -> "input1".equals(x)))).thenReturn("whatever");
Mockito.when(obj.testMethod(Mockito.argThat(x -> "input2".equals(x)))).thenReturn("whatever2");

var substring = obj.testMethod("input1"); //this is "whatever"
var substring2 = obj.testMethod("input2"); //this is "whatever2"
```

Comment: argThat takes in a predicate lambda and whenever the result is true, the matcher will activate. You havent provided any code, so i cannot help here